# Failure to Include php error: looking in the wrong directory despite using both absolute and relative includes

Tags: php, path, include

File structure (fyi I'm on linux server)

Error:

```
Warning: include(./Setup/Setup.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/22/10350022/html/templates/Home.php on line 1

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening './Setup/Setup.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in /home/content/22/10350022/html/templates/Home.php on line 1
```

I have tried several different ways to reach this setup file.

```
tried: include('/Setup/Setup.php') - same error
tried: __DIR__. '/Setup/Setup.php'
tried: $_SERVER [SITEROOT] and some other variations including the total path. 
tried: Include = path ".:/Setup/Setup.php"
```

All three produced the same error with one difference. The path shown in the error included: 
    /var/chroot/home/.../Setup/Setup.php

I'm struggling to understand what is going on here. I'm not super proficient with PHP so I'm not exactly sure how to minipulate the relative v. absolute paths.

Why is it looking in my /templates folder when I told it to look in /Setup?

Thanks!

Comment: what directory is this script in, and what directory is the file you want to include in? e.g. what are their absolute paths, `/path/to/the/script.php` and `/some/other/path/to/the/include/file.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the path is right:

```
   include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Setup/Setup.php");
```

Make sure the PHP user has rights:

Temporary chmod to 777 and test

```
   chmod 777 /home/content/22/10350022/html/templates/Setup/Server.php
```

Comment: UGH the permissions! Thank you! I completely forgot about that. So dumb. Usually I do that first before I start working. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
include('Setup/Setup.php');
```

The above example should work nicely. However, not knowing how you are including the file and your structure you may need to jump back directories by using `../`. Make sure your file is readable as well.